# Endpoint not found when referencing client from another project

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I have two console projects on same solution. One of them (lets call it Client) has a service reference to a .svc file hosted on a local IIS instance with the following app.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:80/Service.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
          contract="WCF.IService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The second one (ReClient) has a reference to Client project in same solution with the following app.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I have done a lot of research for the past three days and found a couple solutions like this:

http://www.tikalk.com/net/keep-wcf-client-configuration-class-library-appconfig

But what my client wants is to maintain the ReClient project with no changes in the code or the app.config file. Is there a way to make a reference to the Client project without changing anything? The Client project which has the service reference to the WCF service can be changed.

Comment: `Client` and `ReClient` have their own individual app configs - they can't be shared.  You'll need to either change the code or the app.config, or come up with an entirely different approach.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm trying to convince everyone that changes need to be applied. I was migrating everything from asmx to wcf so they didn't want any changes to the clients projects :)